# Is it possible to create std::any with std::reference_wrapper from just std::any?

Tags: c++, c++17, rtti, stdany

Let's say, I have an `std::any` that store type T in it. Is it possible to create another `std::any` that will contain type `std::reference_wrapper<const T>`? Like

```
std::any original = std::string("Test string");
std::any reference;

// Magic here

auto ref = std::any_cast<std::reference_wrapper<const std::string>>(reference); // Works
```

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible, unless you know the exact stored type (see the other answer), or the list of possible types (in which case you can `switch` over `original.type()`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want this badly enough, you can create a little wrapper class around a `std::any` that captures and type-erases the "convert to `reference_wrapper`" operation when it is constructed:

```
class any_refable
{
public:
    std::any ref() const { return converter(any); }

    const std::any& get() const& { return any; }
    const std::any&& get() const&& { return std::move(any); }
    std::any& get() & { return any; }
    std::any&& get() && { return std::move(any); }

    any_refable() = default;

    template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<! std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, any_refable>>>
    any_refable(T&& v) : any(std::forward<T>(v)), converter(make_converter<std::decay_t<T>>()) {}

    template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<! std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, any_refable>>>
    any_refable& operator=(T&& v) { any = std::forward<T>(v); converter = make_converter<std::decay_t<T>>(); return *this; }

private:
    using converter_t = std::any (*)(const std::any&);

    std::any any;
    converter_t converter = nullptr;

    template <typename T>
    static converter_t make_converter() {
        return [](const std::any& any) { return std::any(std::cref(std::any_cast<const T&>(any))); };
    }
};
```

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/6EDNNC)

Comment: Looks interesting. Wouldn't deriving from `std::ANY` provide a bit more intuitive interface tho?

Comment: There are numerous reasons why I would avoid inheritance here, that could fill a whole other question (that would probably be closed for being too opinion-based). Let me quote from three items of Sutter & Alexandrescu's book _C++ Coding Standards_. Item 34: "Prefer composition to inheritance. Inheritance is the tightest coupling relationship in C++, second only to friendship."

Comment: Item 35: "Avoid inheriting from classes that were not designed to be base classes. Using a standalone class as a base is a serious design error. Avoid inheriting from concrete classes. Inheriting from a class with a public non-virtual destructor risks undefined behavior." Item 37: "Inheritance is substitutability. All base contracts must be fulfilled." [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/_oj3Yp) is an example of how inheritance could make it too easy to invoke undefined behavior. Granted, that's possible with composition too, but harder to do by accident.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <any>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::any original = std::string("Test string");
    std::any ref = std::cref(std::any_cast<const std::string&>(original)); 

    std::any_cast<std::string&>(original)[0] = 'X';

    std::cout << std::any_cast<std::reference_wrapper<const std::string>>(ref).get() << '\n'; // Prints Xest string
}
```

Edit: As said in the comment, this only works if the type is known at compile time. If the type of the contained object is arbitrary, it is impossible, since the `std::reference_wrapper` has to be constructed at some point and for this it needs to know the type it has to wrap at compile time, there is no way around this since C++ is statically typed.

Comment: This requires you to know the exact stored type, so it's kinda cheating.